# Some PC games crash for unknown reason

Tags: windows-10, memory, graphics-card, crash

This computer never had any similar problems, and the crashing have started about a week ago. i am really clueless at this point, and i believe i have tried every trick i know to fix the issue, unsuccessfully. 
The crash could happen at any point from the execution of the game, to 2 hours after the game is running. the most common timing for a crash is during a loading, in more demanding games (Squad, Escape from Tarkov, war thunder..)
Things i have already tried to do:
 1. Updating graphics card drivers
 2. Running a memory check on my RAM (no issues were found)
 3. restarting, obviously.
 4. Checking for high temperature, The GPU is averaging around 55c, and the CPU around 44c.

My specs are:
Intel core i5 4430 processor
Gigabyte B85M-HD3 motherboard
DDR3 8GB  798MHz kingston RAM sticks
Geforce GTX 1060 6GB, zotac AMP! edition
one terra of hard drive, and 250gb of SSD.
   games crash on both of them, so i don't believe that they are the cause.

I have owned this computer for at least six years now. i never had the need to replace the whole thing, because i just kept replacing the outdated parts that slowed me down, that's the reason some of my specs are younger than six.

EDIT: escape from tarkov just crashed again, and gave me a [crash report](https://pastebin.com/g8VyQ3P2). not sure how to analyze these, but it might help some one to gget a brighter picture..

Comment: Do you have anything like crash log files or error messages or command line output?

Comment: I once had a message from the  war thunder crash reporter that just stated "Out of memory". which led me to track both my RAM and my VRAM. both seemed to be pretty much clear, (normal use of 30~40% usage) upon crashing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update windows.**
DirectX and Nvidia are OS Dependant, therfore an outdated verision of windows screws things up. 
i guess that updating all of my drivers wasn't a bad idea either.